SVD before clustering method (no dimensionality reduction)
Does it make sense performance-wise to apply SVD to a dataset before applying a clustering method? I mean: is there a statistical reason to do such a thing? Does it depend on the method, on the number of dimensions? Or maybe there's no way of generalizing this?
I'm referring to applying just the SVD, not the full PCA (i.e: no dimensionality reduction)
